# Cursor issues on Wayland KDE

Tags: fedora, kde, desktop-environment, wayland, cursor

I'm using Wayland KDE 5.27 on Fedora 38 and I noticed that there are some issues with the cursor.

First, the cursor looks very blurry, especially the edge but I have anti-aliasing on and the screen resolution matches that of my monitor (1920x1080).

Additionally, the cursor is slightly off the position so that sometimes when I move cursor away from a text input area, it is still "I" shaped and does not change to arrowhead-shaped.  so I was wondering what is causing these issues.